# SimpleXMLElement array retrieval issue

Tags: php, simplexml

How to get Cxyabc, Cxy123 and Cxy234 inside an array from below object?

```
$xml_element = simplexml_load_string($xml,null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$childId = $xml_element->Parent->ChildID;

print_r(childId);

SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [@attributes] => Array (
        [entity] => result 
        [order-value] => 1
    )
    [0] => Cxyabc
    [1] => Cxy123
    [2] => Cxy234
)
```

Thanks for answers, i tried below one and working fine. string conversion is necessary.

```
$test = array();
foreach($childId as $value){
    $strValue = (string)$value;
array_push($test,$strValue);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full code? However `SimpleXMLElement `implements `Traversable`, so you can iterate on the internal collection instance using `foreach ($instance->children() as $node) { ... }`.

Comment: @Praveen: It's a SimpleXML object, it's special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$cxyabc = $obj->{0};
$cxy123 = $obj->{1};
```

The usage of `{ }` is necessary because object properties cannot begin with a digit so `$obj->0` is not valid.

You would access the attributes using array notation:

```
$entity = $obj['entity'];
```